# Detect When HTML Video Ends in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

I'm trying to detect when an HTML `video` ends in Ionic2 (Angular2 and Typescript). My code snippets are below:

Template:

```
<video poster="" id="v" playsinline autoplay webkit-playsinline onended="vidEnded()">
    <source src="assets/vid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Component:

```
vidEnded() {
    console.log("video ended");
    this.leavePage();
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In Angular 2, you need to add `-` between prefix `on` and event name, or simply remove prefix `on` and surround event name with `()` bind an event. So, correct syntax in your case would be one of these two, you can use whichever you prefer because both do the same thing:

- `on-ended="vidEnded()"`
- `(ended)="vidEnded()"`

Check out [Angular 2 binding syntax](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#binding-syntax).

Comment: Perfect, `(ended)="vidEnded()"` worked for me! Thanks!

Comment: I'm using this code and the event isn't fired, any ideas why? <video (ended)="Test(0)" on-ended="Test(0)" #inlineVideo src="https://movie.mp4" class="inline-video" (click)="videoControls()" playsinline autoplay="true" [muted]="mute" preload="auto" loop>Video not loaded yet</video>

Comment: @Dimitri same here on Angular 5, have you found solution?

Comment: @godblessstrawberry if you include loop in your video the (ended) will not trigger as video never ends

Answer (score 14):

You can detect when a Html video ends in Angular in this way:

**Template:**

```html
<video (ended)="videoEnd()">
  <source src="assets/vid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

**Component:**

```js
videoEnd() {}
```